# Read client machine outlook appointments using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have created a sample application in asp.net to read outllok appointments.It works in local when I deploy it on server.It is trying to read  outlook from the server but what I want is,It needs to read the client machine outlook appointments with provided username and password by the client.

Comment: Should this work in an Intranet or over the Internet?

Comment: Are you re-inventing Outlook Web Access (OWA)?

Comment: I got answer.Actually i need to connect the excahnge server ans read the inbox.
THe below links helped me to find the solution.

http://weblogs.asp.net/psperanza/archive/2008/03/18/getting-calendar-items-using-exchange-web-services.aspx

http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2008/03/20/Using-Exchange-Web-Services-2007-The-Basics/

Thank you all(@chrfin ,@Filburt )for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer.Actually i need to connect the excahnge server ans read the inbox. THe below links helped me to find the solution. https://weblogs.asp.net/psperanza/getting-calendar-items-using-exchange-web-services